# Difference between Surefire provider and runner specified using @RunWith annotation at Class level

Tags: java, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

As per documentation of Surefire plugin, we can specify a provider to be `JUnit 4`, `JUnit-47` and others.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Suppose I have a class as mentioned below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyListener{

    @Test
    public void testProp() {

    }
}
```

When we run maven surefire, will it use `junit47runner` or `PowerMockRunner` to run the test case?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `@RunWith` is a JUnit annotation (which complies with what is set in your xml config, so **you can drop that dependency xml config part** and don't worry about that).

JUnit runner will in turn run your `PowerMockRunner`. So your powermock will be enabled but you still can use JUnit things like `@Rule`.

Also since junit 4.7 it's recommended that instead of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` you use [JUnit powermock rule](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/powermockrule).

--

Quoting [surefire doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html). For the general part of the question.

> In some cases it may be desirable to manually override such a selection. This can be done by adding the required provider as a dependency to the surefire-plugin.

Which means that if properly set, surefire config takes over.